# One row or the other row but not both

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I select one row or the other but not both.

**Table example:**

*Component*

- ID : int (PK)
- Name : nvarchar(120)
- Damaged: bit
- BaseComponentId : int (FK)

**Description**

I would like to select all the components from the *Component* table, but if there is an undamaged component, I would like it to be selected, otherwise the damaged component should be selected. However, they can never be selected both damaged and undamaged. Of course, the grouping is done over BaseComponentId.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Please provide a sample data and desired outputs as _formatted text_ not images.

Comment: Show what you have attempted so far. Sample data and desired results will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by BaseComponentId order by convert(int, damaged) asc) as seqnum
      from components c
     ) c
where seqnum = 1;
```

This returns exactly one row per base component with a preference for a non-damaged one.

You can also use a correlated subquery:

```
select c.*
from components c
where c.id = (select top (1) c2.id
              from components c2
              where c2.BaseComponentId = c.BaseComponentId
              order by c2.damaged asc
             );
```

Comment: That's an excellent answer, but maybe you know of any other solution that would not require row_number (). That's because I'd like to use it in FlexibleSearch (Hybris), and there are no such functions there.

Comment: In the second query, the subquery should probably include the "top 1". You helped me a lot! many thanks!